# Taking a long time. Transaction pending

Tags: myetherwallet

So I've sent a few tokens from my MEW which I haven't used in a two years and some of the transactions are taking 2+ hours and are still pending.

Does anyone know what I did wrong or what's going on?

My mew address is
Ox28272da8c3814C57B952D2c35399D706B83 C79a3

Comment: What is the GasPrice you set?

Comment: can't find your transaction since the address is invalid. Please Share a link.

Comment: Sorry it's 0x28272da8c3814C57B952D2c35399D706B83C79a3

Comment: I put a gas price of 55 Gwei

Answer (score 2):

You have one "blocking" transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa94a4ce8e7fe6366dcebda3cbbd01b22c1c760988c104f3c16cfab0c85b3f57b

Where you are trying to transfer a token that is `paused` (see details):
https://etherscan.io/token/0x69c4bb240cf05d51eeab6985bab35527d04a8c64#readContract

So it "blocked" the rest of the transactions...

*NOTE:* You need to cancel this transaction.

Comment: Thank you!how can I cancel the transaction through MEW on my desktop?

Comment: Ok thank you for the help. Seems you were right and the OPEN token froze the rest. It seems it all went through now. Thank you all again

Answer (score 0):

I can see your Transaction on the [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa94a4ce8e7fe6366dcebda3cbbd01b22c1c760988c104f3c16cfab0c85b3f57b).
I have concluded 3 Reasons Why your Transaction is pending.

1. You are Trying to send the ether to `Paused` token. Cancel your **First** transaction.
2. Lower Gas Price.
   Today's Avg. Gas Price is about `95 Gwei`. While you just fixed `55 Gwei` So you should try increasing the Gas Price.
3. Pending transactions.
   There are 3 pending Transactions that you have currently.[image].

The Real problem is that the Transaction with the lower nonce( First Transaction) is not selected yet. [image]

**SOLUTION**
If you want make this process faster

1. Increase the Gas price of the 1st pending Transaction. It might be the reason other transactions are struck.
2. OR There is another method. `Child-pays-for-Parent`. Using this method you can increase the Gas Price of your last or second last transaction. Upto 1`20 Gwei`. Due to this the miner have to include your previous unconfirmed Transactions as well.